# Как производить отладку java library module в Android Studio для обработчика аннотаций?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, отладка, аннотации

Для андроид приложения пишу java библиотеку.
В Android Studio библиотека создана как java library module.

Проблема возникла при отладке данной библиотеки.
Точки останова в ней не работают. 
Естественно функцию Log из android.util там невозможно 
применить, т.к. бибилитека java.

Подскажите пожалуйста
как для java library module производят отладку в 
Android Studio ?

=======================================================

Уточню свой вопрос возможно у меня не обычная проблема.
Как отлаживать класс генерирующий код с использованием
`AbstractProcessor`

Вот сам код:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.bignerdranch.android.annotproc.processor.CustomAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class CustomAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{





    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv)
    {



        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
                .append("package com.bignerdranch.android.annotproc.generated;\n\n")
                .append("public class GeneratedClass {\n\n") // open class
                .append("\tpublic String getMessage() {\n") // open method
                .append("\t\treturn \"");


        // for each javax.lang.model.element.Element annotated with the CustomAnnotation
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class)) {
            String objectType = element.getSimpleName().toString();



            // this is appending to the return statement
            builder.append(objectType).append(" says hello!\\n");
        }


        builder.append("\";\n") // end return
                .append("\t}\n") // close method
                .append("}\n"); // close class



        try { // write the file
            JavaFileObject source = processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile("com.bignerdranch.android.annotproc.generated.GeneratedClass");


            Writer writer = source.openWriter();
            writer.write(builder.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Note: calling e.printStackTrace() will print IO errors
            // that occur from the file already existing after its first run, this is normal
        }


        return true;
    }
}
```

Код генерируется нормально. Но когда я ставлю точку останова например в строке

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
                .append("package com.bignerdranch.android.annotproc.generated;\n\n")
                .append("public class GeneratedClass {\n\n") // open class
                .append("\tpublic String getMessage() {\n") // open method
                .append("\t\treturn \"");
```

или в любой другой строке в этом классе, ничего не происходит,
никакого останова нет. 
Как проводить отладку такого кода ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Создаёшь приложение в котором подключена эта библиотека, а дальше ничем от обычного дебага не отличается. Все брейкпоинты там работают, если у Вас на один или несколько из них не заходит - это проблема кода, а не отладчика.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня ни совсем видимо обычный код. Уточнил свой вопрос конкретным примером.